# Retrofit errorBody as hex

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp

I have problem with working with errorBody in Retrofit.
Our server is adding messages to error responses.
When response code is 4** and it is handled by the server on its own - I get correct errorBody (field in HttpException) as a String. So I just serialize it with Gson.

But problems occurs when I try to read errorBody from response given on 5** 
 response which is sent by ngnix by itself.

In Postman everything is working good and I see correct "Body".

My HttpInterceptor is also logging me correct response body String.

But when I try to handle the error with Retrofit - errorBody in HttpException is written as a HEX.
[image: hex content]

Why it is happening?
Do I have to use HEX converter or I am doing something wrong with Retrofit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It’s only in hex ’cause nothing has tried to decode it into characters for you. You can do that in your debugger by evaluating `readUtf8()` on that buffer.